# Setting collation of full text index on SQL Server 2014 to distinguish 'ss' and 'ß'

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, full-text-indexing, inverted-index

I want to distinguish 'ss' and 'ß' within the full text indexing respectively quering the dynamic management functions of the full text index (`sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` and `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document`), but I can only choose the language of the full text index (GERMAN) and not any kind of (binary) collation.

My local table test_1(id, text) contains two datasets: (1, 'Maße'), (2, 'Masse'). In German *Maße* and *Masse* are two different words, but unfortunately the following query only returns 'Masse':

```
SELECT display_term 
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(DB_ID('Test'), OBJECT_ID('Test.dbo.test_1'))
```

The text column has Latin1_General_BIN as collation. The following query returns only one row as it is supposed to do:

```
SELECT text 
FROM test_1 
WHERE text like '%Maße%'
```

How can I configure the database or table or full-text-index to achieve a distinction between words containing 'ss' and 'ß' for quering the dynamic management functions of the full text index (`sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` and `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document`)?